# How to get data in UI when routing to a new page in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes

I added a routing

```
{
            label: 'Dummy Notification Summary',
            name: 'dummy notification',
            path: '/overview/dummy-notification?siteId',
            component: lazy(() =>
                import('@abc/main-dashboard').then(({ DummyNotification }) => ({ default: DummyNotification }))
            )
```

in my AppRoutes component. So when I click on Dummynotifications, it will land me here. I want to pas some data in this page. I tried passing HelloWorld by creating two other files like **HelloWorld.tsx**

````
import { FC } from 'react';
export const HelloWorld: FC = () => <h1>Hello World</h1>```

 and called HelloWorld in DummyNotifications.tsx like 

```import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HelloWorld } from './HelloWorld';

export class DummyNotification extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HelloWorld />
       </div>
    );
  }
}```

But nothing is showing up in the UI. Can someone please tell me how can I show Helloworld in the UI! Thanks in advance.
````